# How to close 30 open ms-word files with python code?

Tags: python, ms-word

I'm using python 2.7.8. I'm working with 30 open docx files simultaneously.
Is there some way with python code to close all the files simultaneously instead closing every file separately ?

UPDATE:

I'm using different files every day so the names of the files change every time. My code must generally without specific names files (if it is possible)

Comment: So are you opening and working with the word files in python?

Comment: yes,i have a lot of word file so i use python

Answer (score 0):

I suggest is using the `with` statement when opening files:

```
with open('file1.txt', 'w') as file1, open('file2.txt', 'w') as file2:
    file1.write('stuff to write')
    file2.write('stuff to write')
    ...do other stuff...

print "Both files are closed because I'm out of the with statement"
```

When you leave the `with` statement, your file closes. You can even open all of your files on one line, but it's not recommended unless you are actively using all 20 files at once.

Comment: how can i close all files without mention the name files?

Comment: Open() can function as a context manager. It will open the file when you enter the with statement, then automatically close it when you exit. This stops you for have to write code to track your files.

Answer (score -1):

You need to find the pid of your word files and then use kill method to terminate the word file's process. e.g

```
import os
os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

Comment: where can i find the pid?

Comment: You can use psutil library to get info about all the running processes using psutil.get_pid_list() . Visit this link to download psutil and view its documentation https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=display&name=psutil#down:loads

Answer (score -1):

first you have to append all opened file object in list.

```
l = []
f1 = open('f1.txt'):
    #...do something
l.append(f1)
f2 = open('f2.txt'):
    #...do something
l.append(f2)
```

Now get all files object from list and close them.

```
for files in l:
    files.close()
```

Comment: i didn't understand you sorry

Comment: first when you open any file just append file object(f1, f2) in a list.
Then Now when you want to close this files, just forloop on list, it will give you file objects one by one and close file pbjects using 'files.close()'
Does it make sense? Let me know

Comment: the code does not work also it run and no error happened